# sending buffer region to the repl in emacs

Tags: emacs, scheme

i'm using quack mode with mzscheme, is there a way to send(evaluate) the whole toplevel contents to the REPL window? i checked the key bindings but i don't see any commands for this, there are options only for sending last sexp, last definition etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C-c C-r - scheme-send-region, but sometimes it more handy to use C-x C-e to evaluate expression before point... These functions are defined in cmuscheme.el, that should be loaded from quack.

You can look to [my article](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsScheme.html) about working with Scheme from Emacs

Comment: thanks for the link, i'm checking it out now.

is it possible to evaluate without highlighting the region, like the slime option slime-eval-buffer?

Comment: Yes, there are lot of eval command, that should be available from Scheme menu in Emacs - you can see the keybindings for them there... To evaluate whole file it's better to use C-c C-l, that will load file into scheme interpreter

Answer (score 4):

There is the binding <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> which is bound to `'scheme-load-file`, which will allow you to load the file for the current buffer.